# Add minutes to timestamp

Tags: java, date, timestamp, java-5

I need to add minutes into timestamp and return new value after that. Timestamp is taken from database and passed to method as String and has this pattern: yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSSSSS

```
public static String changeCreditTimeStampMin(String tmStmp, int minutesToAdd) {

    tmStmp = tmStmp.substring(0, tmStmp.length() - 3);
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS");
        java.util.Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(tmStmp);
        java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime() + minutesToAdd*60*1000);
        tmStmp = timestamp.toString();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return tmStmp;
}
```

As you can see, my logic uses SimpleDateFormat and in order to use that I have to use substring operation on timestamp. My question, is there any better way I could get the same result without cutting the timestamp string? Please note that my java version is 1.5 and I cannot use newer versions.

Comment: Seeing as you pass around your timestamp as a String, no, you will need to parse the String to modify the time. Do you really need the timestamp to be a String? Otherwise it might be better to use it as a number in you program, especially if you need to do more operations on it.

Comment: Are you concerned about the loss of precision or the sequence of operations?

Comment: @Oebele I don't need it as String but it is what i am getting from DAO classes, in fact I have many variables retrieved from result set as string, so I don't to touch that class.

Comment: @rpy No, I am not concerned about precision, I could pass returned value back to database query and compare it with timestamp that have initial pattern and it would work fine. I just want to know if i could use something without string manipulation(substring operation) as it just doesn't seem to be right to me.

Comment: I meant to say that, if you need to do many operations on the timestamp, it is better to convert it to a number once, when you retrieve it from the database, keep using it as a number in your program, and covert it back to a string only when you use it in a query again.

Comment: @Oebele I see what you are saying, i would do the same, but the program that call this method is passing the value as a string and expects return value as a string, this method was using only substring operations to return string, I modified it to use SimpleDateFormat and Timestamp but it still uses substring in one place, and I would prefer not to touch classes that calling this method.

Comment: Did you try using sufficient places for sub-seconds? like `"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSSSSS"` for parsing to match what is sent into the conversion?

Comment: @rpy you mean did I pass "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSSSSS" into SimpleDateFormat? It doesn't accept it, gives me exception.

Comment: Hm,, could not reporoduce the problem her. Maybe you could add a sample input timestamp string and the exception on ...SSSSSS... format and/or the exception in case of not using substring....?

Answer (score 0):

The issue for you is that you are using mm. You should use MM. MM is for month and mm is for minutes. Try with yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm

Other approach:

```
static final long ONE_MINUTE_IN_MILLIS=60000;//millisecs
Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance(); 
long t=date.getTimeInMillis(); 
Date afterAddingTenMins=new Date(t + (10 *ONE_MINUTE_IN_MILLIS));
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way?

Yes, use java.time classes rather than the old legacy date-time classes.

Change your string input to standard ISO 8601 format by replacing the space in middle with a `T`. I assume this string was intended to represent a moment in UTC. So, append a `Z`, short for Zulu, meaning UTC.

The java.time classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating string representations. So feed directly to the parse method without bothering to define a formatting pattern. An `Instant` represents a moment on the timeline in UTC with a result ion of nanoseconds.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( input );
```

Add minutes. If you want this in UTC, so you don't care about handling time zones and anomalies like Daylight Saving Time (DST), use this `Instant` to create another. Otherwise apply w time zone to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
long minutes = 5L;
Instant later = instant.plus( minutes , ChronoUnit.MINUTES );
```

Tip: Pass these `Instant` objects around your app rather than strings.